# RealURL: caching or not?

Tags: typo3, realurl

Upon fiddling with a RealURL config, I noticed that I had unknowingly turned off RealURL caching, as in this old post http://blog.marit.ag/2007/07/24/realurl-pathcache-ausschalten/

As of 2015, are there still reasons to disable RealURL Caches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urs, I have no idea why blog's author gave that statement but it's generally wrong. Have no idea what kind of problems they encountered (maybe if they described it, it had some sense), anyway best solution is proper RU configuration instead of disabling the cache.

Keep in mind that general rule in TYPO3 is - cache, as much as possible, as long as possible.

If you'll meet some problems, then you can just clear the RU cache (currently probably by truncating RU's tables in DB, as dedicated ext have some problems with TYPO3 ver. 6.2) and try to fix the configs.

I just checked RU configs in several installations for my own curiosity, to check if is there is somewhere disabled RU cache, result: 0.

Comment: yeah, tell me pls @Urs, does `realurl_clearcache` work for you in 6.2+ ?

Comment: Ah, btw, now we have a case when disabling RU cache helps: when there is a misconfiguration as in my http://stackoverflow.com/q/28720006/160968 - as I have assigned unstable keys for realurl-matching, caching will unmask that error by rendering "wrong" URLs when the unstable keys change.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is aboslutely bad (I would even say **evil**) idea to disable realurl caches. Don't do that and never listen to anybody, who tell you to do so.

The option to disable caches was made only for time when you create the site and rename/move pages frequently. In order to prevent cache pollution, it can be disabled. Production systems absolutely **must** have realurl caches enabled.

Comment: Thanks! Occasional readers, note that Dmitry ist THE authority on realURL, as he is the author :-)