# In extbase, how to access item by another value than uid

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

In a custom extbase extension, I need to call a show action, passing it another value than `uid` (this is a continuation of [Use other than primary key as RealURL id_field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28720006/160968)).

As the value "other than uid" is not resolved, it results in the exception http://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1297759968

EDIT: here's the current working (but ugly) Controller code:

```
/**
 * ItemController
 */
class ItemController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

    /**
     * itemRepository
     *
     * @var \STUBR\Weiterbildung\Domain\Repository\ItemRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $itemRepository = NULL;

    /**
     * action list
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function listAction(\STUBR\Weiterbildung\Domain\Model\Item $item=null) {
        if (!empty(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET('tx_weiterbildung_pi1'))){
            $this->forward('show');
        }
        $items = $this->itemRepository->findAll();
        $this->view->assign('items', $items);
    }

    /**
     * action show
     *
     * @param \STUBR\Weiterbildung\Domain\Model\Item $item
     * @return void
     */
    public function showAction(\STUBR\Weiterbildung\Domain\Model\Item $item=null) {
       $tx_weiterbildung_pi1_get = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET('tx_weiterbildung_pi1');
       if (!empty($tx_weiterbildung_pi1_get)){
        $dfid = intval($tx_weiterbildung_pi1_get['durchfuehrungId']);
       }
       $items = $this->itemRepository->findByDurchfuehrungId($dfid);
       // helpful:
       //\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($item);
       $this->view->assign('item', $items[0]);
    }
}
```

PS here are the 5 lines that could be used in the Repository if the magical method wouldn't work:

```
//public function findByDurchfuehrungId($dfid) {
//  $query = $this->createQuery();
//  $query->matching($query->equals('durchfuehrungId', $dfid));
//  return $query->execute();
//}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you're using actions with model binding in param it will always look for object by field defined as ID - in our case it's always `uid`, but remember, that you do not need to bind model automatically, as you can retrive it yourself.

Most probably you remember, that some time ago I advised to use `<f:link.page additionalParams="{originalUid:myObj.originalUid}"Click here</f:link.page>` instead of `<f:link.action...>`

In that case your show action would look like this:

```
public function showAction() {
   $item = $this->itemRepository->findByOriginalUid(intval(GeneralUtility::_GET('originalUid')));
   $this->view->assign('item', $item);
}
```

Where `findByOriginalUid` should work *magically* without declaration, but even if it doesn't it's just matter of 5 lines in the repo ;)

**Other sample**

According to the code you pasted I'd use it rather like this, in this case `listAction` gets a role of dispatcher for whole plugin:

```
public function listAction() {
    // access get param in array
    $tx_weiterbildung_pi1_get = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET('tx_weiterbildung_pi1');
    $dfId = intval($tx_weiterbildung_pi1_get['durchfuehrungId']);

    if ($dfId > 0) { // tx_weiterbildung_pi1 exists and is positive, that means you want to go to showAction
        $item = $this->itemRepository->findByDurchfuehrungId($dfId);
        if (!is_null($item)) { // Forward to showAction with found $item
            $this->forward('show', null, null, array('item' => $item));
        }else { // Or redirect to the view URL after excluding single item ID from GET params
            $this->redirectToUri($this->uriBuilder->setArgumentsToBeExcludedFromQueryString(array('tx_weiterbildung_pi1'))->build());
        }
    }

    // No `tx_weiterbildung_pi1` param, so it should be displayed as a listAction

    $items = $this->itemRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('items', $items);
}

/**
 * @param \STUBR\Weiterbildung\Domain\Model\Item $item
 */
public function showAction(\STUBR\Weiterbildung\Domain\Model\Item $item = null) {
    $this->view->assign('item', $item);
}
```

Your finder should also `getFirst()` object if possible:

```
public function findByDurchfuehrungId($DfId) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->matching($query->equals('durchfuehrungId', $DfId));
    return $query->execute()->getFirst();
}
```

Comment: Isn't the magic function `findByUid()`? As all magic functions in the repository `findBy[COLUMNNAME]()`

Comment: @konsolenfreddy my question is a little incomplete original_uid / originalUid is the field I have to look up. will try that asap

Comment: Why would you not use `<f:link.action>`?

Shouldn't it just work by doing this: `<f:link.action action="show" arguments="{originalUid: myObj.originalUid}">...</f:link.action>` in fluid, and with the action method: `public function showAction($originalUid) {...}`, where `$originalUid` is annotated with the correct type?

This way seems more "correct": it is easier to avoid parameter name collisions.

Comment: Another way would be to write your own type converter. It would probably extend `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\ObjectConverter` and have a higher priority (> 1), but would only return `TRUE` in `canConvertFrom` if the target type is your model. In the `convertFrom`-method, it would then just query the repository, and throw an exception if it does not find an object in the database. You would need to register it in `ext_localconf.php` and trigger its use in the "initialize[ActionName]Action()" method.

Comment: @Jost the reason for not using <f:link.action> is that it creates ugly URLs, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26145125/160968

Comment: @biesior Thanks again! I've pasted my current controller above (now with the real variable names). I've had to make the get query two times, as it wasn't able to pass the value peacefully to the showAction. What do you think? And two more questions: 1: all this seems to be a lot of work to make extbase behave like "normal" procedural php. Or not? 2: I always have to add namespaces like `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\`to static methods like the one above, is that inserted by your IDE?

Comment: @Urs check my edit,  __Jost__ the reason for not using `f:link.action` are the redundant `...[action]` and `...[controller]` params, de facto they could be avoided in 98% of cases, unfortunately I didn't find the way to do it

Comment: I see, I didn't realize the repository could be accessed already in the listAction. And it works! Uffffff. I've edited your solution so the get param is taken from an array.

Comment: Ok, you should check then if `$tx_weiterbildung_pi1_get` `is_array` first ;)